# Location of appcache in IE

Tags: html, html5-appcache, ie-developer-tools

What is the storage location(filesystem) of appcache in IE? Are there tools in IE similar to Chrome(chrome://appcache-internals/) or Firefox (about:cache) to view/delete them?

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows 7 VM with IE11 installed (from Modern.ie) the app cache location is 
`C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\AppCache\O92JC8EP\21` for me; the `21` can be a different number.

As per a tool to check the manifest, I know of none, but there is an `appcache.man[1]` file in the above directory which you can open in Notepad.